# SetWindowsHookEx, KeyboardProc and Non-static members

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I am creating a keyboard hook, wherein KeyboardProc is a static member of a class CWidget.

```
class CWidget
{
   static LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );

};
```

I want to call the non-static members of CWidget inside the CWidget::KeyboardProc.

What is the best way to do it?

KeyboardProc does not have any 32 bit DWORD where I can pass the 'this' pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that you probably only want one keyboard hook installed at a time, just add a static pThis member to your class:

```
// Widget.h
class CWidget
{
    static HHOOK m_hHook;
    static CWidget *m_pThis;

public:
    /* NOT static */
    bool SetKeyboardHook()
    {
        m_pThis = this;
        m_hHook = ::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, StaticKeyboardProc, /* etc */);
    }

    // Trampoline
    static LRESULT CALLBACK StaticKeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        ASSERT(m_pThis != NULL);
        m_pThis->KeyboardProc(code, wParam, lParam);
    }

    LRESULT KeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    /* etc. */
};
```

You need to define the static member:

```
// Widget.cpp
CWidget *CWidget::m_pThis = NULL;
```

Comment: now i have to set all member of my class to static to use them in method. do you have any idea not to happen that?

Comment: That's what the `m_pThis->KeyboardProc` bit does -- trampolines into a non-static context. That means that only the static `KeyboardProc` needs to be static.

Comment: this didn't work for me: `unresolved external symbols: "private: static class keylogger* keylogger::this_"`. On the line where you set `m_pThis = this`.

Comment: You still need to *define* the static member somewhere.