# Passing 'this' pointer to MouseProc of SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: c++, c, winapi, hook

Generally, whenever we want to wrap a Window/Thread in a C++ object, we do so by passing the `this` pointer via `SetWindowLong/GetWindowLong` or `SetProp/GetProp` for a Window, and as `lpParameter` for `CreateThread`/etc.

My question is specific to Hooks. **What is the elegant approach to pass the 'this' pointer to SetWindowsHookEx's callback procedures**, or in other words **How to wrap a hook's callback procedure ?**

Since `SetWindowsHookEx` does not accept any *UserData* argument, I don't see much options apart from using un-encapsulated i.e. global/static/TLS data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SetWindowsHookEx, KeyboardProc and Non-static members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333575/setwindowshookex-keyboardproc-and-non-static-members)

Comment: @RogerLipscombe - thanks for the link. I had seen that already, it talks about using static, which I already know/have done many times. but never found it satisfying.

Comment: It's not satisfying, but it's the "standard" way to do it. If you do something else, it's going to be potentially surprising.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Are you saying using `Thunks` as mentioned by @ybungalobill is potentially surprising? I want to be open to learn new and better ways of doing some same old stuff.

Comment: What I'm saying is this: If you're writing a framework (such as ATL), then using a thunk is probably the right answer. If you're writing an app then prefer the simple (but not as "elegant") solution.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe yes that makes sense from simplicity point of view. Actually problem is if we make it static, then we have to keep a check on instances/or convert the class to singleton, else there will be chaos. That is why I wanted to avoid static/globals.

Answer (score 2):

You are expected to have just one instance of a given hook, so global data is not an issue.

If you are developing a library allowing multiple hook instances that can be dynamically added or removed, do not add multiple hooks at the OS level.  Instead, add a library-level hook procedure that walks the list of hook instances.  Since you maintain this list, you can track whatever "user data" alongside each entry you want.

Comment: Global mapping is something I am avoiding, ultimately its a global variable/outside the encapsulation.

Comment: @subdeveloper: Yeah sorry I was thinking of subclassing (window message hooking) the first time I read the question.  I think I've understand your actual request this time.

Answer (score 2):

The 'most elegant approach' is to use a **thunk**. It's a small piece of code generated at runtime that holds your `this` pointer. This is the approach that ATL uses even for regular windows.

See

- [What is a thunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641489/277176)
- [How to generate the code for thunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11507789/277176)
- [C++ WinAPI Wrapper Object using thunks (x32 and x64)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1121696/Cplusplus-WinAPI-Wrapper-Object-using-thunks-x-and)

Comment: Elegant in theory but in practice this involves lots of undefined behavior, is non-portable, and likely to trigger anti-virus.

Comment: @BenVoigt: this is literally how **all ATL** works. Never trips an antivirus. And it's as portable as your windows app will be.

Comment: Thanks for pointing there, I believe I've read about thunks and specially how ATL used to use it. I agree its elegant, but probably you will agree its dirty work, and may be difficult to maintain. Or do you suggest otherwise?

Comment: @ybungalobill: Win32 source code can be compiled to x86, x64, ARM (as WinCE).  So no, the thunk is not as portable as the rest of the app.

Comment: @subdeveloper: I would say it's less dirty than the alternatives (having a global map with a global critical section).

Comment: Thunks are neither elegant nor portable. C++ lambdas, on the other hand, are at least portable. It requires [a bit of work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45365798) to allow a capturing lambda to be used in place of a function pointer, but that's to be expected when doing *anything* in C++.

Comment: @IInspectable: do you have an example of how to pass a stateful lambda to a winapi function? I would like to see it.

Comment: I linked to a Q&A that does. What am I missing?

Comment: Apparently, it does. `void foo(void (*fn)()){ fn(); }` looks like a C pointer to me alright. Might be a Microsoft-specific extension to its compiler that allows C++ lambdas to match C-style function pointers (including an appropriate calling convention), but I haven't looked into the language specification to verify.

Comment: @IInspectable: that the linked code uses a singleton static that can support at most one lambda at a time. This is the same as just having a single global variable holding a pointer to your only instance of your class.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are going to delete that comment, too, like the previous one, once you find out that the code shown outlines a concept, and can be adjusted to meet the requirements in this Q&A.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191929/discussion-between-ybungalobill-and-iinspectable).